# generate pdf file from database table in yii using tcpdf extension

Tags: php, pdf, yii

I want to generate a pdf file from database table in Yii framework using tcpdf extension, the extension is in protected/extensions file, using this code (i am not using composer)

```
public function actionCreatepdf() {
    $path = Yii::$app->basePath;
    require_once($path . '/extensions/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
    $pdf = new TCPDF();
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
    $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');
    $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
    $pdf->SetHeaderData('', 0, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, '');
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array('helvetica', '', 8));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array('helvetica', '', 6));
    $pdf->SetMargins(15, 18, 15);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(5);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(10);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
    $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 7);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFillColor(255, 0, 0);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0);
    $pdf->SetDrawColor(128, 0, 0);
    $pdf->SetLineWidth(0.1);
    $pdf->SetFont('');
    // Header
    $tbl_header = '<table border="1">';
    $tbl_footer = '</table>';
    // Data        
    $tbl = '';

    $sql = "select * from personal";
    $data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll(); 

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        $tbl .= '<tr>' .
                '<td>' . $data[$i]['first_name'] . '</td>' .
                '<td>' . $data[$i]['surname'] . '</td>' .
                '<td>' . $data[$i]['age'] . '</td>' .
                '</tr>';
    }

    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
    $pdf->Output("Student_Details.pdf", "D");
    Yii::app()->end();
```

return $this->render('createPdf'); 
    }

i have this error

```
PHP Compile Error – yii\base\ErrorException

frontend\controllers\CvController::actionCreatepdf(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced1\frontend/extensions/tcpdf/tcpdf.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')
```

in the statement

```
  require_once($path . '/extensions/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

what is the wrong with the path and how to make it right? please help.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, in system generated path, there are backslashes and you used forward slashes. This is system specific. Your code might work on Unix which uses backslashes in file paths instead of forward slashes in Windows.

You should change this line:

```
  require_once($path . '/extensions/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

to

```
  require_once($path . '\extensions\tcpdf\tcpdf.php');
```